# Overloading S3 functions with different parameters in R

Tags: r, oop, overloading, generic-function, method-dispatch

It is a follow up to the posted question [Create a function with different arguments in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091625/create-a-function-with-different-arguments-in-r/55093647#55093647)

I created a generic function but got stuck with passing different set of parameters to these functions

```
modelBuild <- function(x, ...) {
    UseMethod("modelBuild")
   }

modelBuild.auto.arima <- function(x, ...) {
      forecast::auto.arima(x)
  }
```

Now, I want to add a parameter `model` into `modeBuild.ets`

```
modelBuild.ets <- function(x, model, ...) {
     forecast::ets(x, model = model)

   }
```

and a different parameter in `nnetar`

```
modelBuild.nnetar <- function(x, repeats, ...) {
     forecast::nnetar(x, repeats = repeats)

   }
```

The `modelBuild` function is called by another function

```
forecast_all <- function(data, algo_name, model = "ZZZ", repeats = 20 , ...) {

  class(data) <- c(class(data), algo_name)

    modelBuild(data, model, repeats, ...)


   }
```

Now, we test on a reproducible example

```
set.seed(1)
a <- runif(100) * 2.5
forecast_all(a, "auto.arima")
Series: x 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
        mean
      1.2946
s.e.  0.0666

sigma^2 estimated as 0.4475:  log likelihood=-101.19
AIC=206.38   AICc=206.5   BIC=211.59




forecast_all(a, "ets", model = "ZZZ")
ETS(M,N,N) 

Call:
 forecast::ets(y = x, model = model) 

  Smoothing parameters:
    alpha = 1e-04 

  Initial states:
    l = 1.2947 

  sigma:  0.5194

     AIC     AICc      BIC 
385.1151 385.3651 392.9306
```

the `nnetar` results in error

```
forecast_all(a, "nnetar", repeats = 22)
Error in 1:repeats : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In avnnet(lags.X[j, , drop = FALSE], y[j], size = size, repeats = repeats,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

---

Inorder to correct it, I included all the parameters as input in each of the `modelBuild`

```
modelBuild.auto.arima <- function(x, model, repeats, ...) {
          forecast::auto.arima(x)
      }


modelBuild.ets <- function(x, model, repeats, ...) {
     forecast::ets(x, model = model)

   }

modelBuild.nnetar <- function(x, model, repeats, ...) {
 forecast::nnetar(x, repeats = repeats)

  }
```

Now, all the functions work as expected

```
forecast_all(a, "auto.arima")
Series: x 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
        mean
      1.2946
s.e.  0.0666

sigma^2 estimated as 0.4475:  log likelihood=-101.19
AIC=206.38   AICc=206.5   BIC=211.59

forecast_all(a, "ets", model = "ZZZ")
ETS(M,N,N) 

Call:
 forecast::ets(y = x, model = model) 

  Smoothing parameters:
    alpha = 1e-04 

  Initial states:
    l = 1.2947 

  sigma:  0.5194

     AIC     AICc      BIC 
385.1151 385.3651 392.9306 

forecast_all(a, "nnetar", repeats = 22)
Series: x 
Model:  NNAR(1,1) 
Call:   forecast::nnetar(y = x, repeats = repeats)

Average of 22 networks, each of which is
a 1-1-1 network with 4 weights
options were - linear output units 

sigma^2 estimated as 0.4297
```

Is this the best practice to create generic functions in `R` or is there a way to define a method with limited parameters for each `methodBuild` can still call it without having to define parameters that are not required for a particular function. I am looking for a similar behavior of overloading functions as in `java`

Can this be solved in `S4` or `R6` method system?